# Multiple databases with webservice interconnection for oracle

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I have three applications based on `Spring Framework`. They are very interactive with each other. Here is an illustration of what we have now:
[image: Current Situation]

Note that application #1 cannot see Database #2. Now I want to perform this query on application #1:

```
SELECT * FROM TB1 JOIN TB2
ON TB1.ID = TB2.FR
```

But as you can see this cannot be done. Now I want an architecture like this:
[image: Desired]

Can I perform such an architecture?

Comment: You'd probably be better asking over on dba.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks.